# Get jade Select box value in NodeJS

Tags: html

Hi I am working on very simple web page made in jade

```
body
    form(action=path method='post')
        .leftframe
            img

        .rightframe

            table(some options..)
                tr
                    <p>question1

                tr
                    <p>choose your answer
                    select(name = question1)
                        option(value = 'a')
                        option(value = 'b')
                        option(value = 'c')
                        option(value = 'd')
                        option(value = 'e')
                        option(value = 'f')
```

this is my jade file

and I just want to get the value of select box which is selected with NodeJS

Is there any way to solve this?

I couldn't find the solution and I am asking here..

Comment: Try doing a tutorial on HTML forms and see what you can discover: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_forms.htm

Answer (score -2):

Not really a "Jade" question

But this should do the trick

```
req.body.question1
```